# Viewpager with fragments screwed up after the system destroyed activity (to recover memory)

Tags: android-fragments, memory-management, android-viewpager, destroy

I have a viewpager with 3 pages and a fragment (containing inner fragment) on each page. My fragments and the activity communicate directly between each other via saved references (I don’t use interfaces or callback). Also I deactivated rotation, my application is used only in portrait mode so far. I call setOffscreenPageLimit(3) and I never call setRetainInstance().

The application works perfectly when it is launched after being properly destroyed.

But when the application is started after the application was destroyed by the system to recover memory and resources (I do this by pausing my app and launching a few heavy applications), viewpager does not start/attach fragments “normally“ and everything screws up.
I have nullpointerexceptions everywhere. For example, my reference to the activity (saved in onAttach) in a fragment is often null. I used to Runnable to give time but even after 2 seconds, though my traces indicate that all fragment callback functions till onResumed have been called,  isAdded() return false and getActivity() return null inside the fragment. Even for the fragment that is supposed to be first displayed. Sometimes some fragments are correctly added.

Of course, the difference between the two scenario above is that in the non-working scenario something happens in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) . There may be an attempt to reused fragments or whatever.  So a workaround is to deactivate the saving of the activity state like that:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

This workaround works but I lose the possibility to use onRestoreInstanceState in the future.

If you have run across this issue, what other nicer solutions have you found? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue you were facing and found that your snippet worked perfectly for me! Thanks!